# How to set different background colors for each header column of a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, subclassing, qheaderview

I have successfully used the following Qt code in my python application to color horizontal headers in a QTableWidget with distinct background colors:

```
header2 = widget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
purple = QColor(139,103,153)
header2.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(purple)) 

header3 = widget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
orange = QColor(237,168,89)
header3.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(orange))
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

However, in my C++ Qt plugin for an existing application, the equivalent logic does not work for the QTableWidget horizontal headers, but does work for table cells or QTableWidgetItem.

The C++ application has it's own style with a dark theme.  If I replace the style with plastique, then my code works.

```
QApplication::setStyle("plastique");
```

However, this is not an acceptable solution, as it changes the appearance of the entire application.

I have searched the web and stackoverflow for a solution and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30888126/259538) seems relevant.  It appears to be subclassing QHeaderView, but the implementation is a little advanced for me.  Unfortunately, the post above does not solve work in my case.

Am I on the right track?
Can someone provide a little more detail about the .h and .cpp and main() implementation?

Comment: What do you not understand about the solution? To say that it is advanced for you does not imply that it is not duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does QHeaderView::paintSection do such that all I do to the painter before or after is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847252/what-does-qheaderviewpaintsection-do-such-that-all-i-do-to-the-painter-before)

Comment: It is not clear how to implement.  What do the .h and .cpp files look like.  Does the code in main resemble my python logic and now just work?

Comment: The code should be something similar to the following, I recommend reading about inheritance since that is the primary part `class Header: public QHeaderView{

protected:
 void paintSection(QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, int logicalIndex) const
 {
     QVariant bg = model()->headerData(logicalIndex, Qt::Horizontal, Qt::BackgroundRole);
     painter->save();
     QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
     painter->restore();
     if(bg.isValid())               
         painter->fillRect(rect, bg.value<QBrush>());             
 }
}`

Comment: In the next question there is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366163/read-model-data-with-custom-qheaderview

Comment: You should paste the image, not link to it.  Many firewalls block links, so fewer people can help you.

Comment: How do I make the QTableWidget header utilize the newly defined class called Header?

Comment: your_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeader(new Header);

Comment: I called tableWidget->setHorizontalHeader(new Header);  Code runs without errors, but my QTableWidget now appears without a header and it appears that paintSection is never called?